# Sending announcements/messages to specific subgroups?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, powerapp, microsoft-flow, announcements

I am creating a new Sharepoint site for an organization who's members can be categorized into Member Types and Committees. Each member can belong to multiple member types and multiple committees. I'm trying to create a way to easily create a news post/announcement/somehow email or notify members that may belong to a specific group or set of groups.

I want to create a way for a given user to select a (or set of) committees or member types (or select all members), put in a subject line and rich-text message, and it to be sent to members of those committees/member types.
Is this possible? I've been trying to figure out something in Microsoft Flow based on the below:

Custom members list with the following columns:

1. Member Name (People type)
2. Position name (text)
3. Related Committees (checkboxes through lookup function)
   Member types (checkboxes through lookup function)

Custom Announcements List (with columns Subject, Message, Send to all?, Committees to send to, Member types to send to) with a Microsoft Flow that responds on new item.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use email. Create AD Groups, mail-enabled distribution groups or Office 365 Groups and let your users send email to the groups.  Do you need something that email does not do?

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/admin/email/create-edit-or-delete-a-security-group?view=o365-worldwide